# How To Use Recursive CTE (SQL) and Multiply by Parent Quantity on Bill of Materials

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, recursive-query

**Background:**

I need to run a report that totals how many of each sub-item (child) I will need based on 2 things:

- A bill of materials (BOM). This comes from a BOM table in the database.
- How many of the parent items are required.

I currently have a SQL script using a recursive CTE that will provide me the correct totals for **ONLY** level 1 of the BOM. After level 1, the extended quantity calculation is incorrect as you will see below. So I need help to make the correct calculation.

**My Example Code:**

```
declare @multiplier int
set @multiplier = '8';

WITH CTE (ProdBOMNo, ItemDescription, ItemNo, QtyPer, ExtendedQty, PBLevel)
     AS
(   
    SELECT BL.[ProdBOMNo], BL.[Descript], BL.[ItemNo], BL.[QtyPer], BL.[QtyPer] * @multiplier, 1 AS LVL
    FROM [dbName$BOMLine] BL
    WHERE BL.[ProdBOMNo] = '008722'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT BL2.[ProdBOMNo], BL2.[Descript], BL2.[ItemNo], BL2.[QtyPer], BL2.[QtyPer] * @multiplier, PBLevel + 1
    FROM [dbName$BOMLine] BL2
    INNER JOIN CTE ON CTE.[ItemNo] = BL2.[ProdBOMNo]
)

SELECT
CTE.[PBLevel],CTE.[ProdBOMNo],CTE.[ItemNo],CTE.[ItemDescription],CTE.[QtyPer],CTE.[ExtendedQty]

FROM CTE
LEFT JOIN [dbName$BOM] BOM ON BOM.[No_] = CTE.[ProdBOMNo]
```

- The parent BOM is 008722 in this example
- The user of the report inputs a parameter (multiplier) in SSRS for how many units they need, in this example I've set the parameter to '8'

**The code above produces following results:**

| Level | BOM No. | Item No. | Item Description | Qty. Per | Extended Qty. Required |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 008722 | 007327 | Pump Assembly | 2 | 16 |
| 2 | 007327 | 007448 | Pump Body | 3 | 24 |
| 3 | 007448 | 007392 | Flange for Pump | 4 | 32 |
| 4 | 007392 | 007395 | Flapper for Pump | 1 | 8 |

**What I want to see is:**

| Level | BOM No. | Item No. | Item Description | Qty. Per | Extended Qty. Required |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 008722 | 007327 | Pump Assembly | 2 | 16 |
| 2 | 007327 | 007448 | Pump Body | 3 | 48 |
| 3 | 007448 | 007392 | Flange for Pump | 4 | 192 |
| 4 | 007392 | 007395 | Flapper for Pump | 1 | 192 |

- So currently Level 1 is correct. Quantity 2 of item # 007327 are required per 008722. (2 * 8 (the multiplier) = 16)
- The SQL script currently just simply multiplies the qty. per by the multiplier/parameter but this becomes incorrect after level 1.
- At level 2 (and lower), it should instead multiply the qty. per by the extended qty. required of its parent.
  So for level 2 in the first example above its currently calculating 3 * 8, when the calculation should actually be 3 * 16.

I am not sure how to adjust the code to get the results I'm looking for but would appreciate any help here.
Please let me know if more data or information is needed and I will provide it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close, you just need to replace your multiplication by the Multiplier with multiplication by the ExtendedQuantity from the recursion

```
declare @multiplier int
set @multiplier = '8';

WITH cteTab as ( SELECT * FROM ( VALUES 
  ('1', '008722', '007327', 'Pump Assembly', '2', '16')
, ('2', '007327', '007448', 'Pump Body', '3', '24')
, ('3', '007448', '007392', 'Flange for Pump', '4', '32')
, ('4', '007392', '007395', 'Flapper for Pump', '1', '8')
    ) as TabA(Lvl, BOMNo, ItemNo, ItemDescription, QtyPer, ExtQtyReq) 
) 
,CTE (ProdBOMNo, ItemDescription, ItemNo, QtyPer, ExtendedQty, PBLevel)
     AS
(   
    SELECT BL.BOMNo, BL.ItemDescription, BL.[ItemNo], BL.[QtyPer]
        , CONVERT(INT, BL.[QtyPer] * @multiplier) as ExtendedQty
        , 1 AS LVL
    FROM cteTab as BL
    WHERE BL.BOMNo = '008722'

    UNION ALL

    --SELECT BL2.BOMNo, BL2.ItemDescription, BL2.[ItemNo], BL2.[QtyPer], BL2.[QtyPer] * @multiplier, PBLevel + 1
    SELECT BL2.BOMNo, BL2.ItemDescription, BL2.[ItemNo], BL2.[QtyPer]
     , CONVERT(INT, CTE.ExtendedQty * BL2.[QtyPer]) as ExtendedQty --This one field changed
     , PBLevel + 1
    FROM cteTab as BL2
    INNER JOIN CTE ON CTE.[ItemNo] = BL2.BOMNo
)

SELECT
CTE.[PBLevel],CTE.[ProdBOMNo],CTE.[ItemNo],CTE.[ItemDescription],CTE.[QtyPer],CTE.[ExtendedQty]

FROM CTE
LEFT JOIN cteTab as BOM ON BOM.BOMNo = CTE.[ProdBOMNo]
```

Anyway, make that one small change and you get the results you expected

| PBLevel | ProdBOMNo | ItemNo | ItemDescription | QtyPer | ExtendedQty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 008722 | 007327 | Pump Assembly | 2 | 16 |
| 2 | 007327 | 007448 | Pump Body | 3 | 48 |
| 3 | 007448 | 007392 | Flange for Pump | 4 | 192 |
| 4 | 007392 | 007395 | Flapper for Pump | 1 | 192 |

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I think you have figured it out. In my testing however I've run into this error: Msg 240, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "ExtendedQuantity" of recursive query "CTE". So I'm guessing that the "ExtendedQuantity" column needs to be switched to a different data type? Are you able to show what I would need to add to the code to switch it?

Comment: @adhocEY I'll look into it and get back to you shortly, however it would help if you listerd the data types (the table definition) for your BOMLine table

Comment: Alternatively, do an explicit cast to an appropriate DT in your ExtendedQuantity calculation (both in the anchor and recursive portions of the cte).

Comment: @adhocEY, I added an explicit conversion as Ben suggested, give that a try. If it still gives an error, please post your table definition and I'll reproduce that as well. Also look in your table for any unusual values - i.e. NULL or non-integer values.

Comment: @RobertSheahan figured it out. I was able to use: CAST (PBL.[Quantity per] * @ multiplier AS DECIMAL(10,2)) for first part of the CTE then CAST (CTE.[ExtendedQuantity] * PBL2.[Quantity per] AS DECIMAL(10,2)) for the new calculation you suggested. Thanks so much for your help in solving this problem for me! Marking as solved.

Comment: @adhocEY Congratulations, good job! You're very welcome :-)